# Apache Airflow SmartSensor printing logs twice

Tags: logging, airflow

Following is the logging of a custom sensor I built. It seems smart_sensor.py class is printing the logs twice. I suspect some issue either in the custom sensor I had built or issue in the airflow itself. Question is how to fix this issue of duplicate logs?

#### Logs

```
[2021-08-24 10:58:52,655] {taskinstance.py:1321} INFO - Submitting <TaskInstance: testing_lakeview.section_1.task_2 2021-08-24T10:58:51.173702+00:00 [running]> to sensor service
[2021-08-24 10:58:52,667] {taskinstance.py:1142} INFO - Task successfully registered in smart sensor.
[2021-08-24 10:58:52,715] {local_task_job.py:146} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,563] {smart_sensor.py:132} INFO - ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,563] {smart_sensor.py:132} INFO - ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,565] {smart_sensor.py:134} INFO - Processing sensor task ('testing_lakeview', 'section_1.task_2', datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 24, 10, 58, 51, 173702, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))) in smart sensor service on host: 844b653e8cd7
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,565] {smart_sensor.py:134} INFO - Processing sensor task ('testing_lakeview', 'section_1.task_2', datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 24, 10, 58, 51, 173702, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))) in smart sensor service on host: 844b653e8cd7
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,566] {smart_sensor.py:136} INFO - ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,566] {smart_sensor.py:136} INFO - ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,568] {smart_sensor.py:373} INFO - 1 tasks detected.
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,573] {smart_sensor.py:408} INFO - Updated hostname on 1 tis.
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,574] {smart_sensor.py:739} INFO - Loaded 1 sensor_works
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,575] {smart_sensor.py:618} INFO - Sensing ti: ('testing_lakeview', 'section_1.task_2', datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 24, 10, 58, 51, 173702, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')))
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,575] {smart_sensor.py:618} INFO - Sensing ti: ('testing_lakeview', 'section_1.task_2', datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 24, 10, 58, 51, 173702, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')))
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,577] {smart_sensor.py:619} INFO - Poking with arguments: {"cid": "c009", "job_name": "test", "execution_id": "hello_1234"}
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,577] {smart_sensor.py:619} INFO - Poking with arguments: {"cid": "c009", "job_name": "test", "execution_id": "hello_1234"}
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,579] {lakeview.py:45} INFO - Creating: c009 test hello_1234
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,580] {lakeview.py:48} INFO - Checking for {'cid': 'c009', 'job_name': 'test', 'execution_id': 'hello_1234'}
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,598] {smart_sensor.py:470} INFO - Marked 1 tasks out of 1 to state success
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,599] {smart_sensor.py:646} INFO - Task ('testing_lakeview', 'section_1.task_2', datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 24, 10, 58, 51, 173702, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))) succeeded
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,599] {smart_sensor.py:646} INFO - Task ('testing_lakeview', 'section_1.task_2', datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 24, 10, 58, 51, 173702, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))) succeeded
[2021-08-24 11:01:10,600] {smart_sensor.py:747} INFO - Taking 0.056454 to execute 1 tasks.
```

#### Custom Sensor

Following is the definition of the LakeviewSensor I am using,

```py
class LakeviewSensor(BaseSensorOperator):

  poke_context_fields = ('cid','job_name','execution_id')

  def __init__(
    self,
    cid: str,
    job_name: str,
    execution_id: str,
    **kwargs: Any
  ) -> None:
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.cid = cid
      self.job_name = job_name
      self.execution_id = execution_id
      self.log.info('Creating: %s %s %s', self.cid, self.job_name, self.execution_id)
  
  def poke(self, context:Dict[Any, Any]) -> bool:
    self.log.info("Checking for " + str(context))
    # removed
    return True

  def is_smart_sensor_compatible(self):
    # Smart sensor cannot have on success callback
    self.on_success_callback = None

    # Smart sensor cannot have on retry callback
    self.on_retry_callback = None

    # Smart sensor cannot have on failure callback
    self.on_failure_callback = None

    # Smart sensor cannot mark the task as SKIPPED on failure 
    self.soft_fail = False
    return super().is_smart_sensor_compatible()
```

#### Airflow Config

```
[smart_sensor]
# When `use_smart_sensor` is True, Airflow redirects multiple qualified sensor tasks to
# smart sensor task.
use_smart_sensor = True

# `shard_code_upper_limit` is the upper limit of `shard_code` value. The `shard_code` is generated
# by `hashcode % shard_code_upper_limit`.
shard_code_upper_limit = 10000

# The number of running smart sensor processes for each service.
shards = 1

# comma separated sensor classes support in smart_sensor.
sensors_enabled = LakeviewSensor
```

#### Airflow Version

```
airflow - 2.0.2 launched via docker compose.
```

Comment: I `testing_lakeview` task set anywhere else? also, `Checking for..` custom log messages does not appear in logs?

Comment: `Checking for..` Is available as part of the logs above,

`[2021-08-24 11:01:10,580] {lakeview.py:48} INFO - Checking for {'cid': 'c009', 'job_name': 'test', 'execution_id': 'hello_1234'}`